# If $A$ and $B$ are ideals on $R$ and the homomorphism $f:R \to \frac{R}{A}\times\frac{R}{B}$, $f(r) = (r+A,r+B)$ is surjective then $A + B = R$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can anyone help me with a suggestion to solve this problem?

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, $A$ and $B$ are ideals on $R$. If the homomorphism $f:R \to \frac{R}{A}\times\frac{R}{B}$ defined by 
$f(r) = (r+A,r+B)$ is surjective then $A + B = R$

Comment: Take any (p + A, q + B). Then by surjectivity there always exists a r in R s.t. (r + A, r + B) = (p+ A, q + B). What does this tell you about r?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $r\in R$, there exists $a,b\in R$ such that $f(a)=(0,\bar r)$ and $f(b)=(\bar r,0)$. This implies that $a\in A, b\in B$ and $r-a\in B, r-b\in A$. We can write $r=a+b'=b+a', b'\in B, a'\in A$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been trying for a long time.